# Cannot create instance of 'x' WPF Design time

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-3.5, design-time

I have a WPF Usercontrol that displays "Cannot create an instance of 'x'" during design time. At runtime it works fine. I can view it directly when I open the user control, however when I add the user control to another control is gives me this error.

the most inner Stack Trace gives me this:

```
IOException: Cannot locate resource 'cptv/vtimewidget.xaml'.

   at MS.Internal.AppModel.ResourcePart.GetStreamCore(FileMode mode, FileAccess access)
   at System.IO.Packaging.PackagePart.GetStream(FileMode mode, FileAccess access)
   at System.IO.Packaging.PackagePart.GetStream()
   at System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Object component, Uri resourceLocator)
   at BLUE.Controls.CPTV.VTimeWidget.InitializeComponent()
   at BLUE.Controls.CPTV.VTimeWidget..ctor()
```

Possible fixes found online that didn't work

- Clean and build the solution
- Using "pack://application:,,,/Project/..." instead of "../../" for file references

Thank-you

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem. It seems a hickup of VS2015 which is somehow related to i18n and l10n. What help for me was to remove the tag `UICulture` from my `*.csproj` file. Then click `Reload all files` when VS detects the file change. Afterward running the project once I could re-set the `UICulture` without problems.